# What does unknown mean in response to a whois query?

Tags: domain, whois

I performed a whois query through whois.net on a .com domain and for 90% of the fields including Registrant ID and Registrant Name the value is "Unknown".  Isn't this now illegal to not specify valid registry contact details?  I mean there's not even a single e-mail or address on there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whois.net doesn't seem to recursively request information from the internic.net listed whois server.  For example, whois for google.com from [internic's whois](http://internic.net/whois.html) lists the registrar's whois server as whois.markmonitor.com.

Querying whois.markmonitor.com with whois (e.g. `whois -h whois.markmonitor.com google.com`) lists the "full" information that you would expect.

Comment: I doubt that not-recursing would list details as "Unknown". I'd expect the details simply to be missing. Maybe @Supertux can provide an example domain name?

Comment: I stand corrected: the http://www.whois.net/whois/google.com website *does* in fact display "Uknown". Funny people. Use http://www.geektools.com/whois.php instead.